# python: install dash with conda

Tags: python, installation, conda, plotly-dash

How can I install `dash` step-by-step?
I'm really new at importing packages in python. I have python 3.6.4 on my computer and I'm trying to install the dash package, `dash_core_components`.

I tried to type in the anaconda prompt: `conda install dash` (not available for current channels)
I also tried to install pip through conda: `conda install pip` **then** `pip install dash` ... but got an error also.

I'm really new and honestly don't really know what I'm doing. I got a pop-up from spyder when I open it saying to never use pip, it can break stuff. I don't understand why.

Comment: https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started

Answer (score 33):

Here are the commands to get conda to install dash:

```
conda install -c conda-forge dash-renderer
conda install -c conda-forge dash 
conda install -c conda-forge dash-html-components 
conda install -c conda-forge dash-core-components
conda install -c conda-forge plotly
```

If you go to the [Anaconda site](https://anaconda.org/) and search for the package they will give you the conda command to install the package.

Comment: You might want to add `-y` (so you don't have to confirm every time) to each step above.

Comment: Currently `conda install -c conda-forge dash` should be sufficient, it installs all dependencies (renderer, components, plotly...)

Comment: @Lukas You are absolutely correct: the following are deprecated and were moved into dash core: `dash-core-components`, `dash-renderer` and `dash-html-components`. See: https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components

Answer (score 2):

Along with the others. You can also try the following:

```
import pip

pip.main(['install', 'dash-renderer', '--user'])
pip.main(['install', 'dash', '--user'])
pip.main(['install', 'dash-html-components', '--user'])
pip.main(['install', 'dash-core-components', '--user'])
pip.main(['install', 'plotly', '--user'])
```

Note: This will install the packages only for the current session.

or

Try the following too:

```
!pip install dash-renderer
!pip install dash
!pip install dash-html-components
!pip install dash-core-components
!pip install plotly
```

Comment: As of dash 2.1, the following are deprecated and were moved into dash core: `dash-core-components`, `dash-renderer` and `dash-html-components`. See: github.com/plotly/dash-core-components. Remove those lines; all that is required is `dash` and `plotly`.

Answer (score 2):

Per most recent update from [Dash](https://dash.plot.ly/installation) website, the below should **now** be sufficient:

> ```
> pip install dash==1.8.0
> ```
>
> *Note: starting with dash 0.37.0, dash automatically installs
>   dash-renderer, dash-core-components, dash-html-components, and
>   dash-table, using known-compatible versions of each. You need not and
>   should not install these separately any longer, only dash itself.*

Per Lucas's comment above, with [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/dash) distribution use :

```
conda install -c conda-forge dash
```

Answer (score -2):

Try one of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge dash
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken dash
```

It worked for me for a different package (opencv). Source at this [link from anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv)

Comment: You should never install with the "broken" label.